# error: Library "libGL" was not found

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, dependencies, failed-installation

I am trying to install ALBERTA. When run `./configure`, I get this error message:

> checking for main in -lGL... no
>      configure: error: Library "libGL" was not found

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

As the error message indicates: There seems to be no OpenGL library installed on your system. Try

```
sudo apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev
```

to install the missing dependency and then run the `configure` script again.
(Package name and package manager invocation might be different on other than Debian-based systems.)